# select one column as DISTINCT and echo all columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm a newbie in `MySQL`.  I'm writing a code where I need to select only one table as distinct and return all tables.

Here is my database image...

[image]

Here is my MySQL query...

```
`SELECT DISTINCT related_category, pid, id FROM today_offers;
```

I'm getting this output...

[image]

But I Want it to be like this...

```
related_category | pid | id 
Grocery          | n1  | 1
--------------------------
                 | sp1 | 3
--------------------------
Vegetables       | s1  | 4
--------------------------
Bread & Bakery   | s2  | 5
--------------------------
Food             | ad1 | 6
--------------------------
Kitchen          |acd12| 7
--------------------------
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That looks like it has more to do with the way you output it. When you "echo" it in php. The select statement doesn't change.

Comment: Ok when i echo it i want to display product_id ie pid below its related_category. But the dublicate category is echoing multiple times

Comment: To improve the Quality of your Question, please replace your images with formatted text tables, as per your desired output.  Your images have a lot of extra information whereas a text table with field names and sample values would be easier to read, as well as easier to copy values from when working up an Answer.  Also, links to images break over time and should not be exclusively relied upon.

Comment: Don't add images, use formatted text instead!

Comment: In your sample output, what's the value of `related_category` column in the second row? This is not how SQL works. [`DISTINCT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) is just a short for `DISTINCTROW`; what you think you want doesn't make any sense for SQL. You can, however, get all the rows you need then suppress the display of some values in the client code (PHP).

Answer (score 1):

Because I can't comment, I need to post this as answer ..
 1. DISTINCT ONLY THE 'related category'

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 'related_category` FROM `today_offers`
```

Comment: I think his select statement is correct, he just need to change the way of data output

Comment: SQL is NOT a "report generator". It doesn't output blanks to make the data look pretty because that makes it impossible to do things like sorting. Making things "pretty/attractive" for human consumption is done after SQL (in this case PHP).

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this in PHP side like this

**Query :**

```
SELECT`related_category`,`pid`,`id` FROM `today_offers`;
```

**Result array :**

```
        <?php

    $result = array(array("related_category"=>"Grocery","pid"=>"n1","id"=>1),array("related_category"=>"Grocery","pid"=>"sp1","id"=>3),

                array("related_category"=>"Vegetables","pid"=>"s1","id"=>4),array("related_category"=>"Bread & Bakery","pid"=>"s1","id"=>4),

                 array("related_category"=>"Food","pid"=>"ad1","id"=>6),array("related_category"=>"Kitchen","pid"=>"acd12","id"=>7));

    $new_res = array_unique(array_column($result,'related_category'));

    echo "<table border='1px'>";
    foreach($new_res as $key=>$row)
    {
        $i=0;
        foreach($result  as $key1 =>$row1)
        {
            if($row==$row1['related_category'] && $i==0)
            {
                $i=1;
            ?>  
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row1['related_category'] ?></td>
                 <td><?php echo $row1['pid'] ?></td>
                 <td><?php echo $row1['id'] ?></td>

             </tr>   
          <?php
            }
            else if($row==$row1['related_category'] && $i==1)
            {

            ?>  
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                 <td><?php echo $row1['pid'] ?></td>
                 <td><?php echo $row1['id'] ?></td>

             </tr>   
          <?php

            }
        }

    }

    echo "</table>";


    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use group_concat but the result would be like this :

### related_category | pid | id

### Grocery          | n1, sp1  | 1, 3

### Vegetables       | s1  | 4

### Bread & Bakery   | s2  | 5

### Food             | ad1 | 6

### Kitchen          |acd12| 7

```
SELECT related_category, group_concat(pid) AS pid, group_concat(id) AS id
FROM today_offers
GROUP BY related_category
```

OR

You can use 'cursor' in a 'stored procedure' and check if the category repeated, then set to empty string.

Hope it helps..

Comment: Use group_concat how?

Comment: You're answer isn't really an answer without showing OP how to use group_concat here...

Comment: Try this :
SELECT related_category, group_concat(pid) AS pid, group_concat(id) AS id
FROM today_offers
GROUP BY related_category;